# Own mediawiki/wikipedia naming convention for pages

Tags: mediawiki, wiki

I recently installed a mediawiki at home and I'm looking for a way to name pages.

Let's say I have the following structure :

- Main - Dev - C# - Tips
- Main - Cooking - Mexixan Cooking - Tips
- Main - Annoying my girlfriend - Tips

Each final page is a different Tips page. Naming them only "tips" won't work because I need three different pages.

Now, I could name each of my tips page with its "path" (ex: main_cooking_mexican_cooking_tips) but it looks cumbersome and the problem is that, whenever I'll change the structure of my mediawiki, some pages will need to change their name in order to be corrects.

Does it exist some convention to follow regarding this ?

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you could think of a unique name for each subpage (e.g. something like `Mexican cooking tips`?), I think the best way would be to use [categories](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Categories). So, you would have category `Main`, which would contain subcategory `Cooking`, which would contain subcategory `Mexican cooking`, which would contain article `Mexican cooking tips`. If you want to rename a category, you would need to change all articles (and subcategories) in that category, but there are tools to automate that (e.g. [AWB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:AutoWikiBrowser)).

---

Another option is to use [subpages](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Subpages). This way, you would have pages named like `Cooking/Mexican cooking/Tips`. Renaming a part of the hierarchy can be done automatically, as long as there is at most 100 subpages (you can raise this number by setting [`$wgMaximumMovedPages`](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgMaximumMovedPages)).

Also, subpages are disabled by default in the main namespace. To enable them, you need to set `$wgNamespacesWithSubpages[NS_MAIN] = true`.

---

Another option is to combine the two approaches: Use subpages for the last level (or possibly last few levels) and categories for the rest. This way, you would have a page named `Mexican cooking/Tips`, and the page `Mexican cooking` would be in the category `Cooking`.

Comment: I'll have a look at the categories since it's enabled by default. If it's not enough, I'll consider going to the subpages... I'll keep you updated with my final choice, thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/w/index.php?title=Wikipedia:Do_not_use_subpages&oldid=2836167

Comment: @Eroen I'm not sure why you linked to a Wikipedia guideline page from 2004, but that's specific to Wikipedia. On your own wiki, you can do whatever you want.

Comment: Yes. The page describes a lot of non-obvious cons to using subpages, which the WP crowd discovered the hard way, and how categories scale better. This could be useful for mr. Andy, as it provides a counter-point to the apparent simplicity of subpages. Note how most of it is a pro and con list.